# Spring.Net IoC and Magic Strings

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, spring.net

I've been thinking about the IApplicationContext.GetObject(string name) method and it seems to rely fairly heavily on magic strings to get objects from the application context. With other containers like [StructureMap](http://structuremap.sourceforge.net/Default.htm) you can use generics to specify the configuration and request objects but is there a better way than using strings with the Spring.Net IoC container to request objects from the ApplicationContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a wrapper that you call, taking a generic type parameter.

Something like this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    IMyService myService = ApplicationContextWrapper.Resolve<IMyService>();
}


public static class ApplicationContextWrapper
{
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return ApplicationContext.Resolve<T>(typeof(T).Name);
    }
}
```

Not as good as some of the other IoC contatiners, but at least you will get some kind of compiler support.

Answer (score 2):

Spring supports the [CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) via an [adapter](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Spring%20.NET%20Adapter&referringTitle=Home). This interface has [the API](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=API%20Reference&referringTitle=Home) you expected and you also compile against the common service locator so you can switch IoC containers if you want to without having to modify existing code.