# possible GetObjectsOfType replacement

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

I have this small piece of code

```
var idObjects = Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
                      .GetObjectsOfType(typeof (ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething));
foreach (ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething icitds in idObjects.Values)
      icitds.DoSomething();
```

Is there a way i can avoid this by having spring.net automatically inject the singletons to a property i declare, like an array of `ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething`?

The only reason i want something like this is because i want to kill the .dll dependency on the project and this is the single point of usage.

Comment: .dll dependency on which project?

Comment: the project that contains this piece of code is referenced by a webapp that has uses spring.net for DI. If i manage to remove the dependency on spring.net in this project then i will be able to use any other container for any future needs

Comment: I was going through some old spring.net questions and found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107638/spring-net-ioc-and-magic-strings), which led me to the [common service locator project](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/) on codeplex. This project has the same aims as you: to remove the dependency of code on the used IoC container. They do this by introducing common interfaces for service location. You can reference these interfaces from your code instead of the IoC container. Several IoC containers have provided adapters for it, including Spring.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to Marijin's insight this has been nailed!

Firstly consider this all-purpose utility class

```
public class ServiceLocatorImplementer : IMethodReplacer
{
    private readonly Type _forType;
    public ServiceLocatorImplementer(Type forType)
    {
        this._forType = forType;
    }

    protected IEnumerable GetAllImplementers()
    {
        var idObjects = Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
            .GetObjectsOfType(_forType);

        return idObjects.Values;
    }

    public object Implement(object target, MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        return GetAllImplementers();
    }
}
```

declare it with this configuration sample

```
<object id="FindInterfaceUsages" type="ServiceLocatorImplementer, SpringDependendAssembly">
    <constructor-arg name="forType">
        <object type="System.Type" factory-method="GetType">
            <constructor-arg type="string" name="typeName" value="Foo.Bar.IChe, NONSpringDependendAssembly" />
            <!-- i use the strict overload -->
            <constructor-arg type="bool" name="throwOnError" value="true" />
            <constructor-arg type="bool" name="ignoreCase" value="false" />
        </object>
    </constructor-arg>
</object>

<object id="MightyPirate" type="Foo.Pirates, NONSpringDependendAssembly">
    <replaced-method name="GetAllICheImplentations" replacer="FindInterfaceUsages" />
</object>
```

and finally inject to the required target

What is trully great with this methodology is that the underlying GetObjectsOfType is **not** going to be called until you actually execute `GetAllICheImplentations()` (unless you try to execute it during spring init which is not going to bode well)

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [method injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection):

In sharedLib:

```
public class MyService
{
    public void ProcessAll()
    {
      foreach (ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething icitds in GetAllImplementers())
        icitds.DoSomething();
    }

    protected virtual IEnumerable<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething> GetAllImplementers()
    {
      // note that the Spring dependency is gone
      // you can also make this method abstract, 
      // or create a more useful default implementation
      return new List<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething>(); 
    }
}
```

In the web app add a class that implements `GetAllImplementers()`:

```
public class ServiceLocatorImplementer : IMethodReplacer
{
    protected IEnumerable<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething> GetAllImplementers()
    {
        var idObjects = Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
            .GetObjectsOfType(typeof(ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething));

        return idObjects.Values.Cast<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething>();
    }

    public object Implement(object target, MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        return GetAllImplementers();
    }
}
```

And configure method injection in you web app's object definitions:

```xml
  <objects>

    <object name="serviceLocator" 
            type="WebApp.ServiceLocatorImplementer, WebApp" />

    <object name="service" type="SharedLib.MyService, SharedLib">
      <replaced-method name="GetAllImplementers" replacer="serviceLocator" />
    </object>

  </objects>
```

I do feel that it would be better to use the `CommonServiceLocator` (since service location is what you're doing), but using method injection this way, you don't need to introduce an additional reference to `SharedLib`.

Comment: I don't mean to spam, just find this interesting.

Comment: actually this is a great solution and with some configuration type resolution a "generic" ServiceLocatorImplementer is feasible. I already have a utility project that gathers various external dependencies to provide usefull functionality and this "generic" method would go there...

Answer (score 1):

*I'll leave this answer here for future reference, but I like my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026711/possible-getobjectsoftype-replacement/5156853#5156853) better.*

The original answer is rather lenghty and very specific to the example in the question.

I don't think there is a configuration equivalent to `GetObjectsOfType(...)`.

However, isn't it very easy to get rid of the Spring.net dependency?

Let me see if I understand correctly:

```
// sharedLib contains ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething
// by "-->" I mean "depends on"

webApp --> Spring.Core, Spring.Web
webApp --> sharedLib  

sharedLib --> Spring.Core  // only to call GetObjectsOfType(...) on Spring container
```

We want to get rid of the last dependency, because we want to be able to use `sharedLib` in combination with another DI container. In `sharedLib` we have a class that needs to signal all `ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething` implementations to do something.
For this purpose I'd create:

```
MySomethingManager
{
  public MySomethingManager() {}

  public MySomethingManager(IMySomethingDoerProvider prov) 
  { // init SomethingDoers }

  IList<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething> SomethingDoers { get; set; }

  void SignalAllToDoSomething()
  {
    foreach (var doer in Provider.SomethingDoers )
      doer.DoSomething();
  }
}

IMySomethingDoerProvider
{
  IList<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething> GetAll();
}
```

`MySomethingManager` used to contain the Spring dependency, but now it's Spring Free.
Now I have two options when wiring up `sharedLib` with regard to `MySomethingManager`:

1. using property injection on `MySomethingManager.SomethingDoers` with a  `List<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething>`
2. using constructor injection with an `IMySomethingDoerProvider` implementation

Both can be done using Spring and many other DI containers. You can use the first approach
if you don't mind listing all `ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething` in the configuration.

If you want magical `GetObjectsOfType(...)` code, you can use the features of your DI container to create a `IMySomethingDoerProvider`.

When using Spring, the second approach would require to create:

```
MySomethingDoerSpringProvider: IMySomethingDoerProvider
{
  IList<ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething> GetAll() 
  {
    // use Spring.Context.Support.ContextRegistry.GetContext()
    //                  .GetObjectsOfType(typeof (ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething));
  }
}
```

Which you can place in a project that depends on `sharedLib`. Since your `webApp` already depends on Spring.Core, you could place `MyProvider` there to get you started quickly.

*Notes*

If `DoSomething` is called once per instance, you might consider specifying an initialization method instead.

Comment: interesting, however i find that this solution just transfers the dependency somewhere else instead of the sharedLib. Additionally, it introduces at least 2 classes and an interface which have hardcoded logic... which i find inelegant to say the least. I know that this is a valid pattern but i still don't like it

Comment: fair enough ... I have two comments:

Comment: 1 - `MySomethingManager` is an example class - you probably don't have to introduce this class in your project, just place the `SomethinDoers` list on the class that currently has the `GetObjectsOfType(...)`

Comment: 2 - If you go for the first solution (and you don't mind typing out the list of objects that implement `ICustomInterfaceThatDoesSomething`) you don't need `IMySomethingDoerProvider` and its Spring implementation, requiring no additional interfaces or classes at all

Comment: You are right that the dependency on Spring is "just transferred elsewhere" - afaik this exactly what needs to be done when you want to keep `sharedLib` unaware of Spring AND use `GetObjectsOfType(...)` in an application where you _can_ use Spring

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of your question to me is: how to use service locator functions (such as spring.net's  `IApplicationContext.GetObjectsOfType(...)`) from within your library, without introducing a dependency on a specific IoC container.

As stated in the question, this is useful, because we want to build libraries that do not force the consumer to use a specific IoC container. However, we still want to use *an* IoC container, because it eases the development of our library. This dilemma is nicely described by Jeremy Miller in the post ["It’s time for IoC Container Detente"](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2008/08/16/it-s-time-for-ioc-container-detente/).

His blog post has led to a [small project on codeplex called CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/). This project specifies an [IServiceLocator interface](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/27688#332676) for service location, that is implemented by many popular IoC containers, including Spring.NET.

The `IServiceLocator` defines a `IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>();` method, which basically is what is asked for in your question.

When your library needs service locator functionality, you can take a dependency on the CommonServiceLocator library and you and other consumers can wire it up using your IoC container of choice.

And guess what: Spring.NET adapter implements `IEnumerable<TService> GetAllInstances<TService>();` using `GetObjectsOfType(serviceType);`.

Comment: well i'm checking this as the answer, but it's yet another dependency

Comment: Mark Pollack has a [few words to say on the CommonServiceLocator project](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/10/03/the-common-service-locator-library/)