# Service Locator style lookup in Spring.Net - better ideas?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, spring.net

I'm using the following method to get objects from the Spring.Net context by type when I expect to have only one so I don't need to put magic strings in my code. I've seen this area come up in profiles as potentially slow there. Is there a less brute force and better way for me to be doing this?

```
public static T Locate<T>()
{
    var objList = Context.GetObjectsOfType(typeof(T));
    if (objList.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("No object of type: " + typeof(T).FullName + " found");
    if (objList.Count > 1)
        throw new Exception("Multiple objects of type: " + typeof(T).FullName + " found");
    T oneObj = default(T);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry e in objList)
        oneObj = (T)e.Value;
    return oneObj;
}
```

At times I also use this style to pass in run-time parameters. Before someone jumps on me for the anti-pattern... as far as I can tell doing a service locator type pattern is the only way to pass in parameters whose values are only known at runtime.

```
public static T Locate<T>(params object[] arguments) where T : class
{
    var objectNames = Context.GetObjectNamesForType(typeof(T));
    if (objectNames.Length == 1)
    {
        return Context.GetObject(objectNames[0], arguments) as T;
    }
    if (objectNames.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("No object of type: " + typeof(T).FullName + " found");
    }
    throw new ApplicationException("Multiple objects of type: " + typeof(T).FullName + " found");
}
```

Comment: This question might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026711/possible-getobjectsoftype-replacement/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `ServiceLocator` pattern, I suggest you use a [small project on codeplex called CommonServiceLocator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/). It comes with a Spring.net adapter implementation.

This way, your code wil not depend on the Spring container, allowing you to use another container if you want.

In general, I don't think you want to access you IOC container too much from code. Let the container do the wiring ;-).

Comment: I looked at the source to the Spring.Net implementation for CSL and they're doing pretty much the same thing for the locate part.

I'm still curious about the run-time parameters one though.