# Notify parent context object about child context object creation

Tags: inversion-of-control, ioc-container, spring.net

this is a situation I would like to implement.

```cs
public class ComponentRepository 
{
    public void Register(IComponent component) 
    {
        // store component in collection
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- root context -->    
<object id="Repository" type="NameSpace.ComponentRepository" />

<!-- child context (0 - n contexts) -->
<object id="Component" type="NameSpace.Component"/>
```

I would like to register all `IComponent` objects with `ComponentRepository`. I suppose it can be done with some kind of publish/subscribe mechanism, but I would like to keep my classes clean (without implementing any of spring.net interfaces). 
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your question as this: 
After the instantiation of the child-context's `Component`, the Register-method of a `ComponentRepository` defined in another context should be called.

As far as I know, there is no [xml-declarative](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#context-functionality-hierarchy) way to achieve what you want.

I would suggest to either make your `ComponentRepository` `IApplicationContextAware` (which is what you explicitly don't want) or to create a new `IApplicationContextAware` Class which takes a dependency of `ComponentRepository`.

That way you can call the `ApplicationContext`'s `GetObjectsOfType` Method and retrieve all `IComponent` objects to pass to the `ComponentRepository`.

Comment: You could use [method injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection) as an alternative to making `ComponentRepository` `IApplicationContextAware`, for an example see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026711/possible-getobjectsoftype-replacement/5195658#5195658

Comment: Good idea indeed to use a method replacer.

Comment: I used tobsen's solution with little twist. I created new `IApplicationContextAware` class which takes `Component` (instead of `ComponentRepository`) as dependency. Then I used `IConfigurableApplicationContext.ParentContext` to fetch `ComponentRepository` and register `Component`. Thanks for your help.