# Initializing /Accessing Dynamic objects implementing a single interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, spring.net

I am using Spring.Net as my DI in an MVC3 Application with Service Layer - Repository (Nhibernate).

In My Service Layer I am using Chain of responsibility pattern and Would like to initialize a set of rules (Objects implementing a common interface Rule1, Rule2, Rule3). Each class that implements the rule  is stored in DB with Sequence along with the name and can be added or removed.
Example 
 Rule1 : IRule 
         Rule2: IRule 
         Rule3 : IRule

**In My Spring config I Have definitions for all the rules that I have with class names as Id.**

In My service layer I extract all the rule names and have to initialize each rule and execute the rule one after another based on sequence.
My service layer code should not be tied to Spring and hence I don't want to use Service Locator pattern here..

I want to access each of the rule like below. Through a Rule factory Object.

```
public class ServiceLayer 
{
     public Constructor ServiceLayer(IRuleFactory ruleFactory)
     { 
        //Rule factory injected using Spring
     }


     var rules = fetchRulesFromRepoitory();
     foreach( rule in rules)
     {
        var ruleclass =  ruleFactory.GetObject("rule.Name");
        ruleclass.Execute();
     }

}
```

Inside rulefactory what would be my best way of accessing the rule objects which are already defined in the config..  I mean should my rulefactory end up using

```
IApplicationContext.GetObject("Rule1")
```

which again means i am tied to spring here. I figured there is some support in the form of FactoryObject in spring I am not sure whether it can be configured to return me the access to each of the Rule object already initialized by the Spring framework using the Id??..
Or is there a better way of doing things when dynamic objects are to be created..

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026711/possible-getobjectsoftype-replacement - it looks similar to this question.

Comment: Thanks @Marijin the link you have mentioned looks close to what I wanted. I was wondering whether Spring.net has an out of the box support for the same which I am not aware of..

Comment: The closest thing out-of-the-box (afaik) is [lookup method injection](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-method-injection-lookup), which is [one of my answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5195658/322283) to the question linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for but if all your rules are part of the executing assembly at runtime you can do something like this

```
var implementations = (from c in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                               where typeof(IRule).IsAssignableFrom(c) && !c.IsInterface
                               select (IRule)Activator.CreateInstance(c)).ToList();
```

which will create a List of IRule populated with a unique instance of each of your rules.  You'd need to reference System.Reflection and System.Linq

Comment: Thanks Anthony this does work, but i wanted only Spring.net to take my object initialization..